# How to define a variable in the URL in batch?

Tags: batch-file, variables, url

I'm trying to define the variable %anzahl% and make the following curl request with it. But the variable stays unrecognised in the URL.

```
 @echo off
    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

    set /p anzahl=0952-8873
    curl https://thekeepers.org/journals?query=%anzahl% >>thekeepers.xml
    pause
```

Comment: Are you tryin to assign 0952-8873 to the variable name anzahl?  If so remove the /P option.  That asks for user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch `/p` is used for user-input. The stuff behind it is the text shown as prompt to input something.

So you should go for:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
set anzahl=0952-8873
curl https://thekeepers.org/journals?query=%anzahl% >>thekeepers.xml
pause
```